# Scala case class conversion

Tags: scala, type-conversion

Is there a way to convert one case class to another when they have the same fields and inherit from the same trait, without providing a converter function (that would simply do the one to one field mapping)?

For example:

```
trait UberSomething {
  val name: String
}
// these may be located in different files
case class Something(name: String) extends UberSomething
case class SomethingOther(name: String) extends UberSomething

val s = Something("wtv")
//s.asInstanceOf[SomethingOther] FAILS
```

Comment: Shapeless can definitely do this, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23192760/safely-copying-fields-between-case-classes-of-different-types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all never define `trait` members as `val` if they are meant to be implemented at a later point.

```
trait UberSomething {
  def name: String
}
// these maybe in different files
case class Something(name: String) extends UberSomething
case class SomethingOther(name: String) extends UberSomething

import shapeless._, ops.hlist.Align
```

Another approach I've seen somewhere on Stackoverflow before, so apologies for stealing street cred, is to use `Align` such that order of the fields wouldn't matter.

```
class Convert[Target] {
  def apply[Source, HLS <: HList, HLT <: HList](s: Source)(implicit

    // Convert the Source to an HList type
    // include field names, e.g "labelled"
    // Shapeless "generates" this using an implicit macro
    // it looks at our type, extracts a list of (Name, Type) pairs
    genS: LabelledGeneric.Aux[Source, HLS],

    // Convert the Target o an HList type
    // include field names, e.g "labelled"
    // So again we have a (Name, Type) list of pairs this time for Target
    genT: LabelledGeneric.Aux[Target, HLT],

    // Use an implicit align to make sure the two HLists
    // contain the same set of (Name, Type) pairs in arbitrary order.
    align: Align[HLS, HLT]
  ) = genT from align(genS to s)
}
// Small trick to guarantee conversion only requires
// a single type argument, otherwise we'd have to put something
// in place for HLS and HLT, which are meant to be path dependant
// and "calculated" by the LabelledGeneric.Repr macro so it wouldn't work as it breaches the "Aux pattern", which exposes a type member materialized by a macro in this case.
// HLT and HLS come from within genS.Repr and genT.Repr.
def convert[T] = new Convert[T]
```

This is a bit better as the `HList` params are nicely masked as part of `apply` so you don't trip yourself up.

```
val sample = Something("bla")
convert[SomethingOther](sample) // SomethingOther("bla")
```

Let's review this line: `genT from align(genS to s)`.

- First `genS to s` converts the `Source` instance to a `LabelledGeneric`, e.g an `HList` with field info.
- Align aligns the types and fields of the created `HList` for the `Source` type to match the `Target` type.
- `genT from ..` allows us to create an instance of `Target` from an `HList` granted the compiler can "prove" the fields and types are "all there", which is something we already have with `Align`.

Comment: That doesn't actually compile in `gen2 to (gen from obj)`

Comment: Also, "never define trait members as val if they are meant to be implemented at a later point." - can you elaborate a bit or point me to relevant links? Thanks :)

Comment: @Sofia http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642053/when-to-use-val-or-def-in-scala-traits. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @AssafMendelson I've added explanations, I don't have the time to detail more, but I recommend understanding `Generic` and `LabelledGeneric` in shapeless as once you do this will be a pretty simple case of using those typeclasses.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using implicit conversions, eg:

```
trait UberSomething {
  val name: String
}

case class Something(name: String) extends UberSomething
case class SomethingOther(name: String) extends UberSomething

object Something {
  implicit def somethingToSomethingOther(s:Something):SomethingOther = SomethingOther(s.name)
}
object SomethingOther {
  implicit def somethingOtherToSomething(s:SomethingOther):Something = Something(s.name)
}

val s = Something("wtv")
val so:SomethingOther = s
```

Comment: Yes, I know. Creating those conversion functions (implicit or not) is what I'm trying to avoid..